# Prove $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ to be injective

Tags: analysis

The function $f$ from the real set to $\mathopen]-1,1\mathclose[$ is defined as
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
I have to prove it injective.

I supposed there are two reals $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, but came to the result that $a=\pm b$.

What's wrong?

Comment: Keep going. show that if $a=-b$, then $f(a)$ does not equal $f(b)$ (unless $a=0$)

Comment: Ah thanks. I saw that a=b=0 but didn't pay attention they'd be equal if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=-b$, $f(a) > 0$ and $f(b)<0$ or vice versa as denominator being a square root is always positive. They are equal in the case $a=b=0$ So, $a = b$ is implied and hence function is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$; then with a simple manipulation
$$
a\sqrt{b^2+1}=b\sqrt{a^2+1}
$$
Squaring we get
$$
a^2(b^2+1)=b^2(a^2+1)
$$
and therefore $a^2=b^2$. This is probably where you got to. This can be written $|a|=|b|$.

However, from
$$
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}=\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}
$$
it follows that

1. $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$ or
2. $a<0$ and $b<0$.

In either case you conclude $a=b$.